# Move property to parent object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is the object I receive for further processing:

```js
const container = {
    "a": {
        "model": {
            "color": "blue",
            "shape": "round"
        },
        "availability": {
            "eu": "poor",
            "us": "good"
        }
    },
    "b": {
        "model": {
            "color": "green",
            "shape": "square"
        },
        "availability": {
            "eu": "good",
            "us": "poor"
        }
    }
};
```

I'm trying to have the following structure, so to get a property from a nested object and move it up in the hierarchy, :

```json
{
    "a": {
        "color": "blue",
        "availability": {
            "eu": "poor",
            "us": "good"
        }
    },
    "b": {
        "color": "green",
        "availability": {
            "eu": "good",
            "us": "poor"
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to do some modifications with the following code, but nothing was added, only the `model` got deleted:

```js
Object.entries(container).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    key['color'] = value.color;
    delete value.model;
});
```

How to restructure the code above to have the `color` property added to each object?

Comment: `key` is a string. Did you want to use `container[key]` instead? `container[key].color = value.color;`

Comment: value does not have color @Blackhole

Comment: @WillD While I can't speak for the downvoters, it appears to show a lack of debugging and effort. "Ease of answering" is a nebulous criteria, but given that `key` is... an object key (a string) some relatively straight-forward debugging would show that adding a random property to a string isn't going to to what's wanted. IMO the question doesn't show a good-faith effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object.keys(container).forEach(key=>{
    container[key].color = container[key].model.color;
    delete container[key].model.color;
})
```

...rinse and repeat.

Comment: I used this solution, however the `key` should be in brackets `([key])`. Without it, the code didn't work properly.

Comment: @AbreQueVoy, that is not true. You must be using different code then. Maybe you used `Object.entries` instead of `Object.keys`.

Comment: Yep, my bad... Time to get some rest ;-) Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You could destructure and assign new objects to outer properties.

```js
const container = { a: { model: { color: "blue", shape: "round" }, availability: { eu: "poor", us: "good" } }, b: { model: { color: "green", shape: "square" }, availability: { eu: "good", us: "poor" } } };

Object
    .entries(container)
    .forEach(([k, { model: { color }, ...o }]) => container[k] = { color, ...o });

console.log(container);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It works perfectly in dev tools console. But my eslint goes crazy when I put that in VSCode.